# How to set Document Mode in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to set globally in ASP.NET MVC to set Internet Explorer 11 Document Mode to 10? This fixes a format issue that I am seeing.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following -

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
```

You would need to apply this within your _Layout file within the `<head></head>` tags.